Static solution to an implicitly dynamic problem - heat equation
Heat equation
This is the heat equation:
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
   = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}
$
Now let's assume $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$
Then the equation would become:
$
-\Delta u = 1
$
Solving PDE
The equation $-\Delta u = 1$ is solved here. It can be solved for a variety of input 2D or 3D meshes.
For example, consider input to be a 2D square disc with a hole in it:


Question: how to justify the result
Static solution to an implicitly dynamic problem
Now, I cannot justify the final results. What do the results mean?
The assumption of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$ on heat equation would mean that the temperature is going down with a linear slope/rate of -1 then we are getting a static final heat distribution. The final distribution does not vary with time. It's static. What does it mean? Why the temperature is not reducing with a linear slope pf -1? I know the FEM tool we used doesn't consider the time variation. But what's the physical meaning of getting a static solution to a problem that is implicitly dynamic?
I know this might be a stupid question to ask. But I guess I'm missing something here.

@Jon I think for the $u=f(x,y,z,t)$ when I set $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$ then I am assuming $u=f(x,y,z) - t$ , right?

Please don't use rainbow plots, they're difficult to read and often don't even convey what you want it to convey.

@KyleKanos Wow, I didn't know that.

Also, what are your boundary conditions?

@KyleKanos Good point. While solving the PDE, we are assuming homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions corresponding, for example, to zero temperature on the whole boundary. Taken from here: https://mfem.org/tutorial/fem/

@KyleKanos I fixed the rainbow plots :)

Some interpretations that may be useful:

The transient conductive heat equation says that if the temperature is decreasing in some region $\left(\frac{dT}{dt}<0\right)$, then the net curvature of the temperature profile must be downward in that region $\left(\nabla^2 T<0\right)$. (Memorably, in 1D, a frown cools things down, whereas a smile warms things up. Equilibrium corresponds to a straight line connecting fixed-temperature boundaries or satisfying fixed-flux boundaries.)

A constant curvature could arise with a large temperature gradient that decreases somewhat locally, or it could feature a gentle temperature gradient near a maximum where the gradient is zero.

Reflecting this, near a constant-temperature boundary with higher temperatures in the interior, we'd expect a large temperature gradient to direct all the heat from the interior into the boundary. Conversely, in the interior, a gentler gradient may be suitable, as heat has more directions to travel. Near a maximum, all heat flow is outward, so the gradient is relatively small.


Given all this, what temperature profile must exist to produce a uniform rate of temperature decrease everywhere at that moment? One that exhibits a constant net downward curvature: A steep temperature increase near boundaries, leveling off to symmetric maxima in interior regions. Which is what your numerical simulation shows. It's a static image because you've removed any temporal dependence by replacing the time-containing term with a constant.

I enjoy studying your post.

For the 3D space, generically, I have:
$
u=f(x,y,z,t)
$
As pointed out by @Jon when I set:
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1
$
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
   = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = -1
$
Actually, I'm making an assumption here:
$
u=f(x,y,z) - t
$
So, for the 2D example, the resulted graphs are displaying the $f(x,y)$ part of the $u$:
$
u=f(x,y) - t
$
Therefore, the displayed graphs are initial temperatures at $t=0$
Am I right? Looks like I got the answer to my question.

This site is NOT a forum/thread.

@VincentThacker Right. I guess this is the answer to my question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
